# IE7 zoom CSS causes flash movie to move

Tags: javascript, css, flash, internet-explorer, zooming

First, I'd like to point out that this is just for IE7 testing.  I have stripped out all my cross browser code to make it simpler to see what is going on as well as put all CSS in the style attributes of the elements.  I am using the CSS property zoom as a hack to reduce the size of a page in IE7.  I know it would be better to make the code responsive, but I can't for this particular project.  The zoom works as expected except with flash movies.  The code is as follows:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
   <title>Test Page</title>
</head>
<body style="zoom:0.75">
   <object id="movie" class="movieId_1" style="width: 364px; height: 337px; border: 1px solid #000; display:block;">
      <param name="movie" value="/path/to/flash/filename.swf">
      <param name="allowScriptAccess" value="always">
      <param name="wmode" value="transparent">
   </object>
</body>
</html>
```

The object element appears in the right position (as you can see with the border), but the movie inside of it is not positioned properly.  Does anyone know a workaround?  How do you target the styles for the movie inside of the object?

Comment: Yes IE7. Unfortunately we have to support it due to a "new" device that uses it. Drives me nuts with these systems built on old platforms.

Comment: Try wrapping the movie in a position:relative DIV instead of the BODY. If all else fails, put the movie in an Iframe by itself.

Comment: I get the same result with those two things as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This appears to be a bug when wmode is set to transparent.  There doesn't appear to be any workaround for this other than to not have it set at transparent or to use the filter option instead of zoom:

```
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Matrix(M11=0.75,M12=0,M21=0,M22=0.75,SizingMethod='auto expand');
```

The filter option doesn't work always as intended though, so you will need to experiment to see if it works in your case.